# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, docx

I am trying to read a `.docx` file into a `JTextPane`, but its giving some exception. I am using [POI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-poi/info) library. What should I do? Help me out, please. Here is my code:

```
file = new File(
    "C:\\Users\\Siddique Ansari\\Documents\\CV Parser\\Siddique_Resume.docx");
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(fis);// line no 549
extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
String fileData = extractor.getText();
Document doc = jTextPane1.getDocument();      
System.out.println(fileData);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), fileData, null);
```

And this is the `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
at cvparser.ExcelSheet.jButton3ActionPerformed(ExcelSheet.java:549)
at cvparser.ExcelSheet.access$400(ExcelSheet.java:39)
at cvparser.ExcelSheet$5.actionPerformed(ExcelSheet.java:219)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
... 28 more
```

Comment: Looks like your missing a dependency library

Comment: I am using all libraries from poi.

Comment: It would appear that you need [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). This may be a requirement of a sub project. Apache POI has a Maven entry. You could load it and allow Maven to sort out it all out

Comment: I have added piccolo, oldxbean , n saxon9 .. but no change.. same Exception

Comment: _I have added piccolo, oldxbean , n saxon9 .. but no change.. same Exception_ Since none of those libraries contain the missing class, it won't solve your problem. You need to add XMLBeans libraries to your classpath in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I have added All ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) JAR files, for example,

```
  1869113  11-26-12 17:22   poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar
   936648  11-26-12 17:22   poi-3.9/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
  4802621  11-26-12 17:22   poi-3.9/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
```

You'll also need the JAR files from `ooxml-lib` in your `classpath`:

```
   313898  04-05-09 14:28   poi-3.9/ooxml-lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    26514  02-23-11 12:31   poi-3.9/ooxml-lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
  2666695  04-05-09 14:29   poi-3.9/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

Comment: i tried your second suggestion, but i showing joda-time error, then i added joda-time jar. Now its showing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error. Actually what is the problem.

Comment: I switched to `java.time`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24631909/230513).