# Geotools MismatchedDimensionException when using smooth()

Tags: geotools, jts

I am experimenting with Geotools java library, and specificaly with the [smooth](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/jts/JTS.html#smooth-org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry-double-) method. In the  [Geotools documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jts/geometry.html) there is this example:

```
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
Geometry tShape = reader.read(
"POLYGON((10 0, 10 20, 0 20, 0 30, 30 30, 30 20, 20 20, 20 0, 10 0))");

Geometry tLoose = JTS.smooth(tShape, 0.0);
Geometry tTighter = JTS.smooth(tShape, 0.75);
```

when I execute this I keep getting this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/geometry/MismatchedDimensionException

in line `Geometry tLoose = JTS.smooth(tShape, 0.0);` (same happens with next line)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Which version of GeoTools & JTS are you using? What are your imports for the code snippet?

Comment: I am using jts v1.16.1, geotools v22.3. I think the problem is a case of the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372883/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror and I am currently trying to solve it using suggestions in that and other related threads.

Comment: possibly, please add the mvn dependency tree results to the question.